# Optimize Horner Method to Reduce CPE (CSAPP)

Tags: loop-unrolling

Using loop unrolling to reduce the CPE of Horner Method [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ3WH.png)

I have to optimize a question using Horner Method.
Its original solution was:

```
void poly(const double a[], double x, long degree, double *result) {
    long i;
    double r = a[degree];
    for (i = degree - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        r = a[i] + r * x;
    }
    *result = r;
    return;
}
```

I used loop unrolling to reduce its CPE, but the results are always different from the original scheme (>=1e-10).I hope the error can be less than 1e-10.
Here is a portion of the code I wrote

```
for (i = degree-1 ; i >= 4; i-=4) {
        double m1 = a[i - 2] * x;
        double m2 = a[i - 1] * xx[2];
        double m3 =  a[i] * xx[3];
        double m4 = r1 * xx[4];
        r1 = a[i - 3] + m1 + m2 + m3 + m4;
}
double rest = a[i];
for (long j = i - 1; j >=0;j--){
       rest = a[j] +x* rest;
}
*result = r1 + rest;
```

Why did this result occur? Is there an error in unfolding or is it limited by the accuracy of the double?
thanks.